# A question about how to define the centroid of a plane convex body

Tags: general-topology

Let E(2) be the Euclidean plane with its standard metric. Let K be a compact convex subset of E(2) whose interior is non-empty. Is there a geometric or topological definition of the centroid of K, that does not require integration to be performed? Such a definition-by means of a weighted average of points of K-is well known, if K is a finite union of pairwise non-overlapping triangles. But K is not necessarily a polygon, and the only plane convex bodies which have this property are polygons. Furthermore, there is no non-constant mass density defined for the points of K. So the problem is not a problem of mechanics. It is a problem of geometry or topology. Finally, does K always have a unique centroid, and if so, is that centroid always an interior point of K?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centroid is certainly not a topological construct, since if $f$ is a nonlinear homeomorphism the centroid of $f(K)$ is not the image under $f$ of the centroid of $K$.  As for a "geometric" definition, that might depend on how you specify the set $K$ geometrically.  Essentially, you want to 
find a way to do the required integrations without explicitly integrating.
For example, in addition to polygons you could handle segments of circles.

For any bounded $K \subset R^n$ with positive $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, the centroid is defined in terms of integration, and that definition makes it unique.  It is 
also easy to show that the centroid of $K$ can't be separated from $K$ by a hyperplane, and therefore the centroid of a convex set with nonempty interior is in that interior.

EDIT: I should have been more careful here.  Suppose $\overline{x}$ is the centroid of a set $K$ with positive Lebesgue measure.  For any linear functional $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$, we have $f(\overline{x}) = m(K)^{-1} \int_K f(x)\; dm(x)$ where $m$ is $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.  Then the measures of $\{x \in K: f(x) > f(\overline{x})\}$ and $\{x \in K: f(x) < f(\overline{x})\}$ are either both $0$ or both $>0$.  If $K$ has nonempty interior and $f$ is nonzero, they can't both be $0$.  But if $\overline{x}$ was on the boundary of a convex set $K$, there would be a supporting hyperplane at $\overline{x}$, i.e. a nonzero linear functional $f$ with $f(x) \ge f(\overline{x})$ for all $x \in K$.

Comment: Many thanks for clearing up this matter for me. So one cannot avoid having to actually integrate in the general case.  There are many non-empty compact subsets of E(2) which have zero n-dimensional Lebesgue measure for every positive integer n . Some of these-such as finite point sets-also have unique centroids, But I wonder if there are some for which the centroid cannot be defined or is not unique.  It  might be very difficult to answer such questions, if they can be precisely formulated as questions of measure theory.

Comment: If the centroid of K cannot be separated from K by a hyperplane , why can't it be located on the boundary ofK-even if K is convex and has a non-empty interior

Comment: That gives me a good picture of the situation